# 802.11ah Wi-Fi HaLow theoretical network throughput with 100s of clients

Tags: ieee-802.11, speed, throughput, performance

What is the theoretical network throughput of a [802.11ah WiFi HaLow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ah) network with lets say 300 clients connected to a single AP? The networking overhead is supposed to grow with the number of stations and this should make the total throughput smaller.

For example, for 1 MHz channel the with 8 μs GI and MCS 7 the max speed is 3.0 Mbps per spatial stream. Are these 3 Mbps achievable with 300 concurrent clients for download traffic (AP>STA) in theory? I assume an ideal environment without any external RF interference etc. Will the throughput depend on the percentage of download/upload (AP>STA or STA>AP) traffic?

There has been a [throughput test conducted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exhCXCseYdk) by a HaLow chipset manufacturer with a surprising results. They pushed 514 bytes of data to 371 clients in 9 seconds, which results in a data rate of only about 21 KBytes/second (170 kbps). There is no info about bitrate (MCS index) used for this test though but I would expect they try to demonstrate max possible speed which would mean the station count heavily affects the network throughput (3 Mbps vs 170 kbps).